# mcrypt after homebrew install

Tags: php, homebrew, mcrypt

I'm attempting to put together a new laravel application and tried to run php artisan to get the list of commands and it says MCrypt extention required. I am running on OSX Mavericks and ran the mrypt installation from homebrew. So now I"m stuck trying to figure out what I need to do. I am trying to get it ready so I can start messing with Vagrant.

I did go through the commands here through terminal:

```
brew install libjpeg
brew install pcre
brew install libxml2
brew install mcrypt
```

So now I'm trying to figure out why its not letting me run other commands and needing mycrpt enabled even though I already installed it.

I did the suggestions below and still when I try and run php artisan it says mycrypt php extention required.

Any ideas?

Comment: What exactly are you looking for? A list of mcrypt functions? http://php.net/manual/en/book.mcrypt.php

Answer (score 0):

Assuming php 5.5:

```
brew install php55-mcrypt
```

If it doesn't find it:

```
brew tap josegonzalez/php
brew install php55-mcrypt
```

If it complains about not having zlib:

```
brew tap homebrew/dupes
brew tap josegonzalez/php
brew install php55-mcrypt
```

If you're on a different version of php, just change the php55 to match (php 5.3?  `brew install php53-mcrypt`)

Comment: I keep trying to run the laravel artisan command it won't work.

Comment: Did you install php through home brew? Probably a good idea so it all "just works".